# What documents are needed at US port of entry for B1/B2 visa holder?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, paperwork

What documents are needed a port of entry to travel on a B1/B2 visa with dual purpose visit? I have one-day business meeting and I'd like to travel in the US for a couple of weeks afterwards.

I have M Entry B1/B2 stamped on my expired passport; the visa is valid for a few more years. My new passport does not have a visa.

What do I need to show/say at the port of entry?

I am an Indian citizen and travelled to the US a long time ago on business for training. Last time, the length of the training schedule was convincing, but I don't have of that luxury for this trip.

Comment: Do you have any paperwork for the scheduled meeting such as an invitation letter?

Comment: Where are you flying into? The exact paperwork will vary a bit

Comment: @Crazydre how would the paperwork vary depending on the port of entry?

Comment: @phoog It'll affect whether OP will Need the blue form or receive an APC receipt instead. At LAX TBIT and JFK T4 at least, B holders are now directed to APC

Comment: Just curious, what are OP and APC? APC seems like some automatic processing line or something?

Comment: @Seadma OP=original poster, that's you. APC is a kiosk which you can use at some large airports. You answer declaration questions, scan your passport and visa, scan your Fingerprints, take a photo using the camera, and get a receipt. Then you present the passport and receipt to an officer, who interviews and then stamps the receipt and passport. However, at Airports without APC, you Need the blue form they'll distribute on the plane instead, and the fingerpriting and photo will be done by the officer

Comment: @Crazydre you forgot to mention that APC is *Automatic Passport Control.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to present:

- Both passports (the new one open at the main ID page, the expired one open at the visa page)
- Either the blue customs form you get and fill out on the plane (if flying to a non-APC airport) OR the receipt from the APC kiosk (if you fly into an airport where you can use it - in this case you don't need to fill out the form)
- (on request) Invitation letter from the company with contact Details
- (on request) Return flight confirmation.

If they ask, just tell the truth: you'll attend a conference for one day and then travel around as a tourist. No problems with that.

Comment: Thank you kindly. Would a draft invitation letter be available with you? The company is really small and new; in fact I am being invited to help them set-up their online presence and such. Thanks in advance for all the help. Have a terrific day ahead, Friend.

Comment: @Seadma They should have the company name and phone number at the top of the letter, then start by writing "Dear CBP officer", and explain that you are to attend a meeting at this location at this date and time, and briefly explain what it is about. Then sign and if possible stamp it and send it to you via E-Mail in PDF for you to print out and present at the border **only if asked**

Comment: @Seadma Also, like I said: what airport are you flying into, and on what airline?

Comment: Thanks @CrazyDre, I've to go to MSP; but have No direct flights to land there that are affordable now. I need to be there next week. I've NOT yet booked myself. Need to get this letter from clients before booking so that I do NOT risk getting deported back. Thank you for all your help Man. What do you mean by Stamping it? Do they use rubber stamps in US? I thought it was outdated.

Comment: @Seadma No, they use it. The border officials will also stamp your passport and either blue customs form or APC receipt

Comment: Thank you very much. S of course. All entry stamps are done using the same now that I think about it. Is it mandatory? The stamping I mean. Seems like my clients don't have it yet. They should be able to get it done though. Once again, Thanks a million Bro, @crazyDre, May all your dreams come true today!

Comment: @Seadma If they can't, that's fine, but it'll look more legit if they do. Again, though, it is extremely important that they write their phone number in the letter

Comment: Thank you kindly @CrazyDre; I'll ensure the letter has proper contact details. You are a great soul my Friend. If I can be of any assistance ever, count on me. Seadma at rediffmail '.' com

Comment: @Crazydre US businesses do not generally stamp their correspondence.  I can't remember ever having seen such a thing.

Comment: @phoog Good to know!

Comment: That's what I thought @phoog; But as crazyDre said, stamping is done on Passports PoE :) Companies use it regularly here in India. But its archaic in USA. Specially in Tech sector to be precise. Thanks to everyone or your comments.

Comment: @Seadma the US government stamps passports, of course.  But the US government is not a business; it's a government.  Stamps are certainly known in the US, but they're not used as they are in much of Europe to add an official corporate seal to routine business correspondence.  I don't thinkthe practice is archaic in the US, either, it's just that corporate seals have traditionally been used here for a different class of documents.  But I could be wrong about that.